# Activator.CreateInstance throws an exception

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I have this class:

```
public class PlaceLogicEventListener : ILogicEventListener
{

}
```

I have this code trying to create an instance by reflection:

```
public ILogicEventListener GetOne(){
    Type type = typeof (PlaceLogicEventListener);
    return  (ILogicEventListener)Activator.CreateInstance(type.Assembly.Location, type.Name);
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'CrudApp.Tests.Database.DatabaseTestHelper' threw an exception.
  ----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\vd2nxkle.z0h\\CrudApp.Tests\\assembly\\dl3\\5a08214b\\fe3c0188_57a7ce01\\CrudApp.BusinessLogic.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

I am calling the `GetOne()` from the tests dll.
The code of `PlaceLogicEventListener` and the mothod `GetOne()` are both in the same assembly `CrudApp.BusinessLogic.dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passying `type.Name` as a parameter, but `PlaceLogicEventListener` only has an implicit parameterless constructor.

Try:

```
Type type = typeof (PlaceLogicEventListener);
Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be because you need the full name of the type.

try: `return  (ILogicEventListener)Activator.CreateInstance(type.Assembly.Location, type.FullName);`

Also check this thread: [The type initializer for 'MyClass' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398334/the-type-initializer-for-myclass-threw-an-exception)

Answer (score 2):

You were also passing in the wrong assembyly name - it needed the display name.  So :

```
        Type type = typeof(PlaceLogicEventListener);
        var foo = (ILogicEventListener)Activator.CreateInstance(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName).Unwrap();
```

Should do it and also unwrrap the ObjectHandle passed back from CreateInstance.